# Good practice or bad practice on Insert/Update table

Tags: asp.net

I have a page in a website where the user can edit the questions on a poll using two listboxes and two buttons, I'm thinking in doing it this way:

```
Questions in the poll             Questions available
         1             [>]1             0
         3             [<]2             2
         6                              4
         9                              5
                                        7
                                        8
                                        10
```

Here is what the buttons would do:

1. Quit selected from "Questions in the poll"

   Add selected in "Questions available" to "Questions in the poll"

In my way I'd do it Inserting/Deleting to/from the table on where I store the questions in the poll on buttonClick event, but this would cause troubles if anyone is answering a poll and the question disappears...

How would you guys do it? I'm using ASP.NET + VB.NET, but I don't want "teh codez", I just want your opinion on how to do this. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use read/write locks to protect the tables?

You can implement optimistic locking by numerous ways but the fundamental to implement optimistic locking remains same. It’s a 4 step process as shown below:-

```
• Record the current timestamp.
• Start changing the values.
• Before updating check whether anyone else has changed the values by checking the old time stamp and new time stamp.
• If it’s not equal rollbacks or else commit.
```

There are 3 primary ways by which we can implement optimistic locking in .NET:-

```
• Datasets: - Dataset by default implement optimistic locking. They do a check of old values and new values before updating.
• Timestamp Data type: - Create a timestamp data type in your table and while updating check if old timestamp is equal to new timestamp.
• Check old and new value: - Fetch the values, do the changes and while doing the final updates check if the old value and current values in database are equal. If they are not equal then rollback or else commits the values.
```

Lock mode:

```
Shared: 
Used for read operations that do not change or update data, such as a SELECT statement.

Update:
Used on resources that can be updated. Prevents a common form of deadlock that occurs when multiple sessions are reading, locking, and potentially updating resources later.

Exclusive:  
Used for data-modification operations, such as INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE. Ensures that multiple updates cannot be made to the same resource at the same time.

Intent:
Used to establish a lock hierarchy. The types of intent locks are: intent shared (IS), intent exclusive (IX), and shared with intent exclusive (SIX).

Schema:
Used when an operation dependent on the schema of a table is executing. The types of schema locks are: schema modification (Sch-M) and schema stability (Sch-S).

Bulk Update:
Used when bulk copying data into a table and the TABLOCK hint is specified.

Key-range:
Protects the range of rows read by a query when using the serializable transaction isolation level. Ensures that other transactions cannot insert rows that would qualify for the queries of the serializable transaction if the queries were run again.
```

Also [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/114262/6-ways-of-doing-locking-in-NET-Pessimistic-and-opt) should be helpful.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this approach you gave me. If it works, you know what happens.